# How to return single variable from Firebase function forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I created an iOS app that uses Firebase, and I wrote a Firebase cloud function that sends a notification to all app users when there is a new item (post) in the app. I don't want users to get too many notifications, so the Firebase function also saves the notification time to the database. When the function is triggered, it retrieves the time of the last notification and only sends a new notification if a minimum amount of time has passed (currently 24 hours).

My issue is retrieving a variable from inside the forEach loop, specifically the value of the last notification time (variable 'epoch2' in the code below). I cannot see the value outside of the forEach loop. I spent a couple hours trying to solve this, including trying to push the value to an array that had been declared outside of the loop. But even that did not work, the value was not visible once I left the loop.

The only solution that I could get to work was to place the rest of my code (a second forEach loop that loops through all users and sends the notifications) inside the first forEach loop. My code is below. This technically works and accomplishes what I want, but it feels clunky and seems like not the "right" way to do it.

Is there a better/simpler way to retrieve a single value from the first forEach loop that can then remain visible in the rest of the function? I'd appreciate any suggestions.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// function to send notification when there is a new post
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/posts/{postId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

  // current time
  var epoch1 = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);

  // retrieve time of last notification from database
  admin.database().ref("notifications").orderByKey().limitToLast(1).on('value', function(snap1) {
    snap1.forEach(function(childNodes1) {

      var epoch2 = childNodes1.val().date;

      var timeSinceLastNotification = epoch1 - epoch2;

      // only send new notification if it has been at least 24 hours since last one
      if (timeSinceLastNotification >= 86400) {

        var payload = {
          notification: { title: 'New Post', body: 'A new post is available' }
        };

        // loop through all users
        admin.database().ref("users").on('value', function(snap2) {

          snap2.forEach(function(childNodes2) {

            var fcmToken = childNodes2.val().fcmToken;

            // only send a notification if they have an fcmToken in the database
            if (fcmToken) {
              // SEND NOTIFICATION
            }
          })
        })

        // record notification in the database
        var newNotification = admin.database().ref('notifications').push();
        newNotification.set({
          'date': epoch1
        });

      }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: The solution is to use `Promise.all()` which wants an array of Promises and passes the results to a `.then()` callback.

Comment: Don't use `on()` in Cloud Functions.  Use `once()` to query data just once.